# char[] array to textfile, including non-printing control characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, encryption, unicode, streamwriter

I got a quite tricky question (at least for me), i am currently coding a small and simple Encryption and Decryption program which works with polyalphabetical substitution.

This is the Encryption function:

```
static string Encr(string plainText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
        int h = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (h == key.Length)
                h = 0;
            int j = plainText[i] + key[h];
            chars[i] = (char)j;
            h++;
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, false, Encoding.Unicode);
        for (int x = 0; x < plainText.Length; x++)
        {
            sw.Write(chars[x]);
        }
        sw.Close();
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

It's working fine, now my problem is that the outputFile created by StreamWriter contains additional unwanted 00's (due to the Unicode encoding) and 2 totally wrong beginning-values also due Unicode encoding

http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-16ilx4.jpg
(sorry i can't post images directly cause i am < 10rep)

*FF FE* **8A** 00 **A6** 00 **CC** 00 **A4** 00 **B0** 00

bold ones are the correct ones, FF FE in the beginning is completely useless for my encryption/decryption, and the 00's are unwanted (i know this is standard Unicode encoding, my question is how do i achieve it without this encoding but still be able to display the corresponding Unicode chars)

I hope it is clear what i want to achieve, i would like to write out the characters only.
So in this special case to hex-view of the encrypted file would look like this:
***8A A6 CC A4 B0***, encoded as Unicode UTF-8 according to http://unicode-table.com/, so the corresponding letters would be **Š¦Ì¤°**

I have failed so far in all of my attempts to solve this. The solution is probably really easy through...

Comment: You passed in `Encoding.Unicode` so that's what you receive. Try another kind of `Encoding` such as `Encoding.ASCII`,...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters at the start are the 2 bytes of the encoding preamble that identify the encoding that is used. I think you would be better of converting to bytes and writing the bytes to a general binary file without any encoding.

As in:

```
static string Encr(string plainText, string key)
{
    char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (h == key.Length)
            h = 0;
        int j = plainText[i] + key[h];
        chars[i] = (char)j;
        h++;
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes(FILE_NAME, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chars));

    return new String(chars, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: works fine, although i had to move var stream out of using. It caused an error

Comment: This only works for characters with a character code less than 256. A `char` is a 16 bit value, so you need two bytes to represent the encrypted value.

Comment: That's correct, but as this function is intended to encrypt readable text (UNICODE: 0020 (Space) - 007E (~)) and the key-phrase is also readable text it should work flawless.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to use `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: This is one of the shortest answers I've read. it's even not bad.

Comment: because UTF8 encoding will screw it even more: EF BB BF C2 8A C2 A6 C3 8C C2 A4 C2 B0 65 instead of 8A A6 CC A4 B0

Comment: @KingKing It would have been a comment if I had the rep.

Comment: @MaricSlorat I thought of that after I sent.  The true answer is to use a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

What you have appears to be working, but it's not really working. When you have encrypted the character codes, it doesn't make sense to look at them as character codes any more, they are just numerical values. Most values will correspond to some character, but not all.

The correct output from the encryption would be an array of 16 bit integers, not a string of characters. You can then turn the numbers into some textual representation if you like, but you can't use them as character codes and reliably get the same result back when decrypting.

Comment: If both sides use the same Encoding you'll get the same result. All characters are actually representing a simple hex value, i can add and subtract at will, assuming that i only increase/decrease the value of the actual letters (FF FE (Unicode) and the mentioned 00's for example have to stay untouched) and wont go above FF. Just a wild thought.